# java обработка исключений

Tags: java, исключения

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с задачей.

Обработайте вызов рискованного метода в основном методе CatchEmAll, который может вызывать различные типы исключений.
Обратите внимание, что некоторые типы исключений следует обрабатывать, а другие - нет.
Подробности:

IOException -
Оберните исключение IllegalArgumentException с сообщением «Ошибка ресурса» и выбросьте его.

FileNotFoundException-
Оберните исключение IllegalArgumentException с сообщением «Ресурс отсутствует» и выбросите его.

ArithmeticException или NumberFormatException -
Вывести сообщение о сгенерированном исключении в System.err и ничего не генерировать

Любые другие исключения-
Не должно быть поймано

Вот что я написал, но это не работает

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;


public class CatchEmAll {

//You may set another exception in this field;

static IOException exception2 = new IOException();
static ArithmeticException exception3 = new ArithmeticException();
static Exception exception1 = new FileNotFoundException();

public static void riskyMethod() throws Exception {
    throw exception1;
    throw exception2;
    throw exception3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    try {
        riskyMethod();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception1) {
        System.out.println("Resource error");
        throw exception1;
    } catch (IOException exception2) {
        System.out.println("Resource is missing");
        throw exception2;
    } catch (ArithmeticException exception3) {
        System.err.print(exception3.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Как я понял, вначале необходимо создать объекты этих самых исключений, затем пробросить их в методе riskyMethod() в тело основного метода, и там их обработать. Не могу понять почему riskyMethod() не позволяет выбросить последующие исключения exception2 и exception3 (это потому что они наследники Exeption?) Правильно ли я вообще создаю объекты этих исключений? Или мне надо написать код, вызывающий эти самые ошибки своим выполнением?

Comment: "но это не работает" - маленький гномик высовывается из компьютера и говорит "Это не работает"?

Comment: Когда срабатывает первый `throw` исполнение `riskyMethod` останавливается.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Исключение пишется следующим образом:

1. Создается класс - наследник Exception
2. Создается конструктор с аргументом сообщения для вывода

   ```
   public class CustomException extends Exception{
       public CustomException(String message){
           super(message);
       }
   }
   ```

Затем вы его просто пробрасываете где нужно: `throw new CustomException("Сообщение для вывода");`

Что касается теоретической части, то нужно знать о таблице исключений.
Она позволяет определить нам что от чего наследуется, ибо мы не сможем отловить наследника исключения, если до него будем ловить его родителя.

Пример:

```
try{ 
    System.out.print(1/0); // ArithmeticException
} catch(RuntimeException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Этот блок выполнен не будет, т.к ArithmeticException - наследник RuntimeException.
catch(ArithmeticException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Компилирую ваш код. Получаю:

> ```
> $ javac CatchEmAll.java
> CatchEmAll.java:15: error: unreachable statement
>     throw exception2;
>     ^
> CatchEmAll.java:16: error: unreachable statement
>     throw exception3;
>     ^
> 2 errors
> ```

Первый оператор `throw` прерывает исполнение `riskyMethod`. В первую очередь нужно переделать его.

В `main` будем создавать разные исключения в зависимости аргумента в командной строке. `riskyMethod` выбрасывает исключение если оно установлено.

Обратите внимание как обернуть исключение и как обрабатывать несколько исключений в одном обработчике:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CatchEmAll {
    private static Exception exception = null;

    private static void riskyMethod() throws Exception {
        if (exception != null) {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception  {
        if (args.length >= 1) {
            if (args[0].equals("IOException")) {
                exception = new IOException("IO exception");
            } else if (args[0].equals("FileNotFoundException")) {
                exception = new FileNotFoundException("file not found exception");
            } else if (args[0].equals("ArithmeticException")) {
                exception = new ArithmeticException("arithmetic exception");
            } else if (args[0].equals("NumberFormatException")) {
                exception = new NumberFormatException("number format exception");
            } else if (args[0].equals("Exception")) {
                exception = new Exception("exception");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Используйте аргумент IOException, FileNotFoundException, ArithmeticException, NumberFormatException, Exception");
            }
        }

        try {
            riskyMethod();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ошибка ресурса", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ресурс отсутствует", e);
        } catch (ArithmeticException|NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac CatchEmAll.java && java CatchEmAll IOException
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ресурс отсутствует
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:35)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO exception
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:16)
>
> $ java CatchEmAll IOException
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ресурс отсутствует
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:35)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO exception
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:16)
>
> $ java CatchEmAll FileNotFoundException
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ошибка ресурса
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:33)
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file not found exception
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:18)
>
> $ java CatchEmAll ArithmeticException
> java.lang.ArithmeticException: arithmetic exception
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ java CatchEmAll NumberFormatException
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: number format exception
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ java CatchEmAll Exception
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: exception
>   at CatchEmAll.main(CatchEmAll.java:24)
>
> $ java CatchEmAll
> ```